# Spring Reactive Security Test does not consider @PreAuthorize

Tags: spring, spring-security

The controller was configured for service development with spring reactive security, and the `@PreAuthorize` annotation was added for certain endpoints to be accessible only to users who meet the requirements.

I noticed that the `@PreAuthorize` annotation is not running during the implemented test run, so is there anything else I need to do in the implemented code below to confirm this?

Test below:

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@WebFluxTest(ItemController.class)
class ItemControllerTest {
    ...

    @Test
    void testFailsWhenNotAuthorizedUserChangesItem() {
        // Used with CustomUserDetails(long userId, String username, String password, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities)
        webTestClient.mutateWith(mockUser(new CustomUserDetails()))
                     .post()
                     .uri("URL")
                     .exchange()
                     .expectStatus().isForbidden();
}
```

Controller below:

```java
@PostMapping
@PreAuthorize("@itemRoleChecker.hasOwnerRole(authentication, #itemIdx)")
public Mono<ResponseEntity<ResponseDto>> updateItem(...) { ... }
```

(Expected 403 because user doesn't authorized but 200 returned)

Answer (score 2):

`@WebFluxTest` does not setup spring security. This most simple way is to use `@SpringBootTest`.

Or you can refer to an example here to create your own `@TestConfiguration` to start with the spring security layer: [Spring Reactive Security Test does not consider @PreAuthorize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73235749/spring-reactive-security-test-does-not-consider-preauthorize)

---

By looking in to the [@WebFluxTest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/reactive/WebFluxTest.html)  document

> Annotation that can be used for a Spring WebFlux test that focuses **only** on Spring WebFlux components.

It is designed for WebFlux components only, i.e. spring security layer is by design not initialised. This can be helpful when you want to create unit tests regarding the controller layer only. It is significantly faster than using `@SpringBootTest`.

However when your test need some more Spring managed context, you may need to consider to use `@SpringBootTest`, or create some configuration to initialise those things.